# Open with Access not working due to list permissions error

Tags: 2013, permissions, microsoft-access

I'm trying to open a SharePoint 2013 list with Access 2013 which gives me the following error:
[image]

The list has unique permissions and the items within it have item level permissions. Summary of my permissions:

1. Site Collection Admin
2. Full Control on the list
3. Assigned to a group that has Design permissions on the list and Contribute permissions on all items within the list

Comment: Check whether is there any unique permission on that list?

Comment: There are, but so do all other lists. Even the items within the list have unique item level permissions. I am in a group that has Design permissions on the list and Contribute on each and every item in the list.